# How to have accents in my program (e.g. é, è, à, á) - Python

Tags: python, diacritics

I don't have that much experience programming in python, so my question might be very simple. I am working on a project for school, where we need to create an output from a user input (we want to emulate Eliza, but in a very simple way). Right now, the only thing the program does is look for keywords and respond accordingly. However, since I go to a french school and everything is in french, I need to use accents (e.g. é, è, à, á). And this is where the problem arrives: I cannot use accents in my predefined list of keywords (so it's not the keywords from the user input, but in my own program :/ )

Here you have the entire program:

```
#Greeting from bot
print("Salut!")
```

*(Here are the predefined keyword we use to know if there is a negation and if there are any demeaning adjectives in the user's sentence - we'll need to make it a lot bigger in order to make our bot more humanlike but it's just the principle)*

```
negation = ("ne", "n'", "pas", "guere", "ne", "plus", "jamais")
AnD = ("artificiel", "cree", "mecanique", "invente", "concu", "construit", "programme", "innove", "fabrique")
```

But here is the problem: in order to run our program, we had to remove all the accents. So words like *guère, créé, mécanique, inventé, programmé* become *guere, cree, mecanique, invente, programme*, and in some cases it changes the meaning of the word (e.g. *programme* becomes a noun instead of an adjective)

```
adj_neg_decl = None
nega = None

#FONCTION: phrase declarative, pas de negations, adjectif pejoratif
def decl_non_neg_adj_neg(statement):
    if (statement.endswith('.')) and (nega == False) and (adj_neg_decl == True):
        print(AnD_ici + '? Mais moi je suis humain. Ca se voit pas?')
    else:
    #Only for testing
        print('tralalalala')


while True:

    statement = raw_input("> ").lower()

    if statement == "au revoir":
        print("Au revoir!")
        break
```

*(Here we simply look for negations, and adjectives - if you have another (more efficient) way of doing it, I would love to hear your suggestions! I might as well learn some new stuff :) )*

```
    for i in negation:
        if i in statement:
            nega = True
            break
        else:
            nega = False

    for i in AnD:
        if i in statement:
            adj_neg_decl = True
            AnD_ici = i
            break
        else:
            adj_nej_decl = False

    decl_non_neg_adj_neg(statement)

#Reset variables
    for var in (adj_neg_decl, nega):
        var = None
```

I had thought of maybe using unicode or utf-8, but I don't really know how to use it... Is that the right way to go? Or is there something else I can do?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? The unicode handling changed a lot between versions.

Comment: why do you have to remove all the accents ? Do you get error message ? Then show full error message in question.

Comment: Yes, you have to use unicode for your program. In Python 3 it should work out of the box for normal text. In Python 2 prefix your strings with letter u, like u"mécanique".

Comment: Does your Python file define a [source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)? If not: make it so so. always. The default is ASCII for Python 2 and [UTF-8 only for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding).

Comment: _"we had to remove all the accents"_ - you don't have to remove the accents. Python 3 assumes that a script is utf-8 encoded unicode which does support French (and multiple hundreds of other languages). If this is a requirement for school, then let us know. Otherwise, just make sure you write your program in a utf-8 enabled editor and `"guère, créé, mécanique, inventé, programmé"` works.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Python 2, and I think that lists might be a good way to store your keywords.

I could type in the accents directly. For the é, I held down my Alt-key and then pressed these numbers from the numeric keypad: 130. (If you want to find other characters, please search for `windows alt key symbols` in your favorite search engine.)

It might also be helpful to use the `in` operator to tell if a given word is within your list.

Here's an example.

```
>>> AnD = ['créé', 'mécanique', 'artificiel']
>>> 'jamais' in AnD
False
>>> 'créé' in AnD
True
```

Bonne chance!

Comment: That doesn't work in python 2. `'créé'` is still utf-8 encoded (`len('créé')` is 6, not 4) and won't compare against a unicode equivalent (`'créé' != u'créé'`).